# combine results from two queries and order by created_at? [rails 3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Looking for a simple method utilizing active record to grab data from two models, combine the data, and then sort the combined output by created_at.

For example:

assume two models, Comment & Like both belongs_to User

return a combined list of @user's comments and likes sorted by date

I know I can do this in SQL but I'd really like an active record solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe it should be as simple as:

```
combined_sorted = (User.comments + User.likes).sort{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

Comment: this gets me closer, returning both query results in a single array but it does not mix them based upon created_at. It returns comments ordered by created_at followed by likes ordered by created_at. I need all the records mixed together so I get a chronological stream of commenting/liking activity

Comment: This solution works, but has serious performance (memory) issues, since you are loading all records into memory and asking Ruby to do the sorting. I'd love an answer that used the database for the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like (untested):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :activities_by_date, :joins(:comments).joins(:likes).order("created_at desc")
end
```

Then you can do `@user.activities_by_date` and let the db do all the work

Comment: Plus, you're calling scope over user instance. it should rather be: `User.activities_by_date`