# Assosiations in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models ,
Programs 
Subprograms1
Subprograms2

Programs -> has_many :subprograms1 , :subprograms2

Subprograms1 -> has_and_belongs_to_many :Programs

Subprograms2 -> has_and_belongs_to_many :Programs

I want to get all Subprograms1 and Subprograms2 belongs to a particular Programs.

Is it possible in rails.

Thanks in advance......

Comment: exact duplicate of [combine results from two queries and order by created\_at? \[rails 3\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633413/combine-results-from-two-queries-and-order-by-created-at-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you should be able to access all the Subprograms1 and Subprograms2 by just accessing the properties in the Programs model

```
p = Programs.find(10)
sp1 = p.Subprograms1 
sp2 = p.Subprograms2
```

Comment: Do subprograms1 and subprograms2 have the same fields? Why are those separate models?

Answer (score 0):

If the structures in your data are flat (there are no subprograms below other subprograms) you can use Active Record's [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)  to use references to multiple other tables (not only one), so you could set up references from Programs to Subprograms1 *and* to Subprograms2 and retrieve them them all with a single call.

If the structures in your data will be deep (subprograms can have other subprograms) you should rather put all of your 3 tables into one table and use a [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to manage the data tree and retrieve all (deep) subprograms associated with a program. There are [many Ruby Gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting) that can help you in achieving this.

Comment: here my subprograms1 ,subprograms2 has_and_belongs_to_many :programs  ,does polymorphic Association can handle this.